# finding Select box items and clicking on it

Tags: vb.net, casting, webbrowser-control, domdocument, getelementbyid

Hey all i have the following html code on a web page that i am trying to send a click event to; it's a **SELECT tag**. However, i am unable to find it using the following code:

```
Dim element As HtmlElement = bbsmWB.Document.GetElementsByTagName("SELECT").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.GetAttribute("id") = "aPopUp")

element.GetElementsByTagName("OPTION").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.InnerText = "thunder").SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
```

It seems to be due to the fact that the Select tag that i am looking for is within an iframe of that web page.

I am able to get the HTML just fine doing this:

```
theHTML = bbsmWB.Document.Window.Frames("ifrm-rtw32").Document.Body.InnerHtml
```

Within the **theHTML** i found the **aPopUp** code.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<SELECT style="WIDTH: 100%" id=aPopUp onclick=hideMe() size=20>
  <OPTION value=sunny>Sunny</OPTION>
  <OPTION selected value=rain>Rain showers</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=thunder>Thunder Storms</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=snow>Snow Showers</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

How can i modify the vb.net code above in order for it to look in the **iframe** instead of the default page?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like just putting `runat="server"` in the select is too easy of an answer. :)